# Jaxb unmarshaling with new instance eachtime do not unmarshal on second time

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two jaxb unmarshalets created each time I need unmarshal file:

```
private RequestOne getRequest(String requestFile) {
        File file = new File(requestFile);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        RequestOne request = null;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestOne.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            requestOne = (requestOne ) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        return request;
    }
```

And same unmarshaller creation for second time:

```
 private RequestTwo getRequestTwo(String requestFile) {
        File file = new File(requestFile);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        RequestTwo request = null;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestTwo.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            requestTwo = (RequestTwo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        return request;
    }
```

So I have two methods to unmarshal my files xml when **I use only one of them in main mathod scope bouth of them works fine just alone suparatly**. **But when I try to declare them both at the same time in main method scope and execute during main method runs I can not unmarshal second time after first unmarshal method run, no matter `getRequest()` or `getRequestTwo()`**. 
Why this is happend please help&????

Comment: Is the `requestFile` from method argument used in method code as `requestESBFile` variable? What do you mean by the fact that you can't get unmarshal the second time, is there an error logged?

Comment: No I do not get exception. Just after unmarshal second time I have empty object like empty values inside of the object. Yes just made a mistake while edit post. Will change

Comment: AFAIK the `JAXBContext` is thread safe so you're [safe reusing the same instance](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html)  However this is not necessarily related to the problem you're presenting in this post...